# Want to Publish and deploy a web service in my local machine with out using IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, web

My Web Service link:

```
http://localhost:55004/WCFService2/WebService.asmx
```

Please how to do this with out IIS. 
I am using Visual studio 2012 express edition and I dont have "Publish Website" option in build.

I am new to .net and webservices...Please tell me is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Yeah that's not going to happen.. You need IIS to deploy it permanently.

Comment: WCF services can be hosted in their own `ServiceHost` in your application. asmx files will need a web server. There are a few [alternatives to IIS](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=alternative+to+iis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here try this one it may help

"http://ransandeep.blogspot.in/2011/03/publish-webservice-locally-without-iis.html"

Answer (score 0):

Web services cannot be deployed without the use of hosting applications such as IIS.

However if you are using WCF, It can be hosted in following ways.

1. Self Host
2. IIS hosting
3. Windows service
4. WAS

You can pick any suitable hosting method based on your requirements.

There are many tutorials available on the net that provides you with step-by-step process with graphical example regarding this.